# Is there actually any speed impact in SQL 1 query returning 3 columns, or 3 queries returning 1 column?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm wondering about something. I have built a website that heavily uses PHP and SQL (Oracle).

Is there actually any speed impact by doing 1 query returning multiple columns, then multiple queries returning 1 column.

### Example

```
Customer Name:     <?= dbq("select customer_name from customers where customer_no = $session"); ?>
Customer No:       <?= dbq("select customer_no from customers where customer_no = $session"); ?>
Customer Type:     <?= dbq("select customer_type from customers where customer_no = $session"); ?>
```

vs

One SQL query returning 3 columns and then using them:

```
Customer Name:     $row1
Customer No:       $row2
Customer Type:     $row3
```

Comment: 3 queries = 3 roundtrips to the database, 3 trips through the sql parser, blah blah blah. one query with three fields is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One query should be faster. There's significant per-query overhead from parsing the query, searching the table, and returning results to the client. If all your values are coming from the same row, those would only be done once if you combined them into a single query.

Comment: Thanks. So should I do all my queries at the top of the page and then use variables throughout? Is there better practice than such?

Comment: Using an MVC model setup is a more formalised method of what you are suggesting, but in principle, yes, this is best practice.

Comment: @user3973427 It doesn't have to be at the top of the page, it can be right before you use the variables. Either way, you should avoid repeating queries. Consider every call to the database to be the slowest thing you could possibly do (except perhaps a web API).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

- The 3 separate queries will definitely go over the network 3 times and therefore cause 3 times as much network traffic
- They are also different, so the query cache will not be used. You would be better off requesting all 3 columns in all 3 queries (but then the code would look odd, wouldn't it)
- They may also hit the disk 3 times, although I would expect the same data to be buffered already. Of course buffers may be under pressure. This could certainly be the case if the queries were joins or more complex
- The code is also not as readable - its simply more characters and its not clear that the same row of data is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gathered the `STATISTICS` up to date, and have required `INDEXES` at place, followed the `NORMALIZATION` rules. Then, my friend, just go for a single `SQL` and stop worrying about performance right now.

If you really encounter any performance issues, post the `execution plan`, based on which further suggestions could be provided.

If you want a `ROT`, i.e. rule of thumb, then a single query is better than multiple queries divided to do the same task.

**Note** : Performance tuning is all about cardinalities. Cardinality is not about number of columns, but number of rows.

**Update** : And remember, there is a huge difference between `SQL` and `PL/SQL`. Mostly, frontend applications call PL/SQL programs and the `CONTEXT SWITCHING` adds up to the `EXECUTION TIME`.